# Move DataGridView Selected Cell/Row Up/Down On Keys Press Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, keypress

I have a `datagridview1` in my form with one column and unlimited rows hiding its headers using the below codes...

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;   // Hide Row Header
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false; // Hide Column Header
```

So now when we focus on it then first row is already selected and highlighted. Now here I want to use my keyboard UP and DOWN keys to move my selection up and down using the below `KeyDown` function and when I press ENTER then the select cell value should go to class level variable and by default first focus row/cell value should be set to class level variable also...

```
private void datagridview1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGridView1.Visible == true)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Up))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Move UP Row/Cell And Select It");
       }
       if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Down))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Move Down Row/Cell And Select It");
       }
       if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Send Selected Cell Value To Class Level Variable");
       }
       e.Handled = true;
    }
 }
```

Currently I have some class level variable that contain datagridview CELL value that I am getting `CellClick` using below code but I want to do this features on keys using upper code...

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

And my Class level variable is like...

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    string value = "";
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So How can I do it using C#...???

## UPDATE:

For UP/DOWN selection, I used the below code and its working. So now how to send the selected cell value to class level variable on pressing ENTER key...???

```
private void selectUpRow()
{
    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
    int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
    int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
    if (rowIndex == 0)
        return;
    int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex];
    dgv.ClearSelection();
    dgv.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[colIndex].Selected = true;
}

private void selectDownRow()
{
    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
    int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
    int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
    if (rowIndex == totalRows - 1)
        return;
    int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex];
    dgv.ClearSelection();
    dgv.Rows[rowIndex + 1].Cells[colIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I got it working by trying Bla Bla Bla. Here is the short answer with the code...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string value = "";
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Visible == true)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Up))
                {
                    selectUpRow();
                }
                if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Down))
                {
                    selectDownRow();
                }
                if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
                {
                    selectCellValue();
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void selectUpRow()
        {
            DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
            int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
            int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
            if (rowIndex == 0)
                return;
            int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex];
            dgv.ClearSelection();
            dgv.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[colIndex].Selected = true;
        }

        private void selectDownRow()
        {
            DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
            int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
            int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
            if (rowIndex == totalRows - 1)
                return;
            int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex];
            dgv.ClearSelection();
            dgv.Rows[rowIndex + 1].Cells[colIndex].Selected = true;
        }

        private void selectCellValue()
        {
            int rowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
            value = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }

    }
```